# set preferences in widgets using apache Wookie server

Tags: widget

I am using Apache Wookie server for creating widgets.So, I am able to create widgtes but now I need to set some prefernces in my widgets i know there is some mechanism in wookie server but I am not able to figur it out.So, If any worked before on wookie server and set prefernces then please let me know. It is really urget .Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Wookie follows the [W3C Widget API spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets-apis/) e.g.

```
widget.preferences.setItem("name","value");
```